# How do I style my code blocks in a Marp presentation?

Tags: markdown, slideshow, marp

I want to up the font of a code block on one of my Marp slides.

How can I style an individual code block without also effecting surrounding text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that marp respects `scoped` on style tags, apply the style only to the current slide.

The code blocks are likely the only item on the slide using a `pre` tag. Thus

````
---
# I am slide

<style scoped>
pre {
   font-size: 2rem;
}
</style>

```cs
// I am code block
\```

---
````